# I want to remove gesture recognizer when i click on object of a class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to remove gesture when i click on object of a class.

From my side I will try bellow code ,but it is not working . Please help me

```
- (void) registerGesture
    {
       UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTouch:)];
       tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
       [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    }
    - (void) handleTouch:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) gesture
        {
           CGPoint touchPoint = [gesture locationInView:self.view];

           NSArray *viewsAtPoint = [self viewsAtPoint:touchPoint];

           for(TheifView * aView in viewsAtPoint)
           {
             [aView removeFromSuperview];
           }
        }
    - (NSArray *) viewsAtPoint:(CGPoint) point
    {
        NSArray *subViews = [self.view subviews];
        NSMutableArray *viewsAtPoint = [NSMutableArray new];

        for(UIView *theView in subViews)
        {
            if([theView isKindOfClass:[TheifView class]])
            {
                TheifView *theif = (TheifView *) theView;

                CGPoint convertedPoint = [theif convertPoint:point fromView:self.view];
                if([theif pointInside:convertedPoint withEvent:nil])
                {
                    [viewsAtPoint addObject:theif];
                }
            }
        }

        return viewsAtPoint;
    }
```

Comment: Define "not working".

Answer (score 1):

You can use the UIGestureRecogonizerDelagte methods and remove the gesture

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

    if ([self.panGestureRecognizer isEqual:gestureRecognizer]) {

    }
    return YES;
}  

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {


    return NO;
}
```